# Index existing documents on startup

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to elasticsearch and this is a question I've been trying to find an answer to. Basically I have around a thousand documents that I would like elasticsearch to index for me. Do I have to write a bash/python script that would just use CURL to put/post all these documents in my elasticsearch server or can I configure my server so that it would automatically index documents in a specific folder/location on disk when I start it up for the first time?

Answer (score 0):

I far as I know Elasticsearch does not have any option for pulling document to index itself. As you mentioned you need to create a script and push your documents to ES yourself.